AudioWorklet not working when using a PWA on a different device on the same network
so Basically I have an audioworklet named audio-processor.js in the public folder, when i build using npm run build and then serve the pwa , the other device in the network on this line says
audioContextRef.current.audioWorklet.addModule('audio-processor.js'); stating cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addModule')
which means it cant read audioContextRef.current.audioWorklet.
it is able to read audioContextRef.current,
on my localhost there is no such problem why is that?
I tried several things including adding the audio-processor.js in the src folder
